# Reorder dataframe rows based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this `pandas` dataframe:

```
        artist               track   class1  class2     class3
0   Portishead               Roads   0.00    1.00          0.0
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall   0.14    0.86          0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees   0.03    0.97          0.0
```

and these two user input variables:

```
 input_value = 0.80
 input_class = 'class2'
```

from those variables I would like to iterate over the dataframe, 
find the closest value to `input_value`in chosen `class2`, and re-order dataframe rows, like so:

```
        artist               track   class1  class2     class3
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall   0.14    0.86          0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees   0.03    0.97          0.0
0   Portishead               Roads   0.00    1.00          0.0
```

where the closeness of class2 values determines the order of rows.

(`0.86` being the closest to `0.80`, `0.97` second to that and so on..)

so far I have only found the closest value, with the following code:

```
for col in df.ix[:,'class1':'class3']:
    if col == input_class:
        print min(df[col] - input_value)
```

but I'm still a bit far from my goal. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `argsort` on the difference + `iloc`:

```
df = df.iloc[(df[input_class] - input_value).argsort()]

df
        artist               track  class1  class2  class3
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall    0.14    0.86     0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees    0.03    0.97     0.0
0   Portishead               Roads    0.00    1.00     0.0
```

Alternatively, you could use `np.argsort` to the same effect.

```
df = df.iloc[np.argsort(df[input_class] - input_value)]

df
        artist               track  class1  class2  class3
1  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall    0.14    0.86     0.0
2    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees    0.03    0.97     0.0
0   Portishead               Roads    0.00    1.00     0.0
```

---

Use `reset_index` to reorder the index.

```
df.result.reset_index(drop=1)     
        artist               track  class1  class2  class3
0  Yo La Tengo     Our Way to Fall    0.14    0.86     0.0
1    Radiohead  Fake Plastic Trees    0.03    0.97     0.0
2   Portishead               Roads    0.00    1.00     0.0
```

Comment: Maybe I've been up too long... but I didn't get what was going on (-:

Comment: @piRSquared yes... I surprised myself with this too ;-)

Comment: I came to your answer firstly ... and thought it should be a hard question ..LOL

Comment: it is do the same trick like `order` in R :-), thanks, learn new thing ~